# Can we use separate authentication but same database in firebase android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to use separate projects of firebase to access the same database but I want login of both apps are different if I add another app in firebase then it will use same authentication database (login ids), but I want only certain people to access the other app.
How can I do this?